# Maximum flow with time criteria

Tags: algorithm, graph, max-flow

I have a [Flow network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_network). Each edge has `capacity = 1`.

I have to transport all the stuff from the `S` to the `T` in the minimum time. Is there any way to reduce classical [Maximum flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem) to time criteria version?

Comment: There is.  Hint: Max flow is closely related to *what* other problem?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What do you mean with "transport in the minimum time"? How is the amount of time the transportation takes defined?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, for example, max flow is related to min cut.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen, for example, there is 100 gallons of water. The network is a set of pipes. Each pipe joint has an infinite buffer in which water may accumulate. The task is to move all the water from S to T as fast as possible.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen, it seems, that `transport in the minimum time` is fine.

Comment: @JuanLopes, I gave an example in the comment above.

Comment: How long the water takes to go through a pipe?

Comment: @JuanLopes, one pipe takes 1 second.

Comment: There's an upper bound on the amount of water that can arrive at any vertex during any unit of time -- what is it?

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I want to evaluate the time of transportation. I do not know the amount of water.

Comment: You said "For example, there is 100 gallons of water"!

Comment: @j_random_hacker, yep. It was a model of my task... In fact, I have an arbitrary graph with `capacities of edges = 1` and some water.

Comment: If there is no fixed amount of water, then I don't understand what form the answer to this problem would take.  The question appears to be "How long does it take to move an unspecified amount of water through this graph with given edge capacities" -- of course the answer to that must be "It depends on how much water"!

Comment: @j_random_hacker, I have `V` of water. Also, I have the graph with given edge capacities. Also, each vertex has infinite buffer for water. I can control every gallon of water separately.

Comment: Alright, so as I said: There's an upper bound on the amount of water that can arrive at any vertex during any unit of time -- what is it?

Comment: Yes, depending on how much "thing" you want to transport, you may want to choose a path with a larger latency (but also larger bandwidth) instead of a path with low latency but also low bandwidth. Imagine you want to transfer 100 terabytes, would it be better to send over the internet or to mail it? What if it is only 100 kilobytes?

Comment: @JuanLopes: All capacities are 1, so if the min cut is C, I'm thinking it would always be optimal to keep the C edge-disjoint u-v paths ordered (e.g. in a heap) by time-till-next-unit-can-be-delivered-to-T (initially that means by path length), and repeatedly extract the best path (top of heap) and push a unit of water down it.  Each unit of water pushed down a path increases its key by 1, and then it gets pushed back onto the heap.

Comment: @j_random_hacker Yes, all capacities are 1, but there may have flow paths with larger capacity, but also more edges on the way.

Comment: @JuanLopes: I think I see. I've now constructed an example in which the shortest S-T path is not in any C-size (i.e. max-size) set of edge-disjoint S-T paths, which would mean that for sufficiently small volumes (e.g. 1 unit) it's better to just push it along the shortest S-T path instead of the shortest path in some C-size set of edge-disjoint paths.

Comment: @JuanLopes: I think it should be possible to get the best of both worlds.  Initially push units down what I'll call the "fast paths", which are the paths you get by repeatedly finding a shortest S-T path and deleting its edges until this can no longer be done; at the same time, "load up" units along the C S-T edge-disjoint paths (favouring the shorter ones if necessary) whenever this would not cause a bubble in a fast path.